# Заполнение формы через location.hash/search

Tags: jquery, веб-программирование, javascript

Доброго дня. Подскажите как сделать, чтобы при загрузке страницы брались параметры из URL и заполняли форму на этой странице. Генерить сразу нужный html как на Хэшкоде не хочу, на форме несколько селектов - неудобно. Сайт использует ajax-навигацию через location.hash. Может здесь как-то выкрутиться.

Нагуглил даже [пример](http://dark-world.ru/albums/#search=devil&in=titles&style=7&country=0&year=0&sort=0), но не могу разобраться кто/что/как там заполняет форму поиска.

Ткните в нужном направлении. Хотя бы как это происходит в примере.

Answer (score 1):

Ответ: распарсить hash и устанавливать из него поля формы. В примере это делается скриптом query.js. За парсинг URL отвечает плагин jQuery.query. Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю как тут форматировать, и сегодня не узнаю, но надеюсь поможет. Для удобства использовал jQuery

```
<html>  
<head>  
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">

(function () {
  var AjaxSearch = function () {
      var $this, data, hash, DetectHash = function (func) { // функция для отслеживания изменения хеша  
          setInterval(function () {
            if (hash != window.location.hash && window.location.hash) {
              hash = window.location.hash; // устанавливаем новый хеш  
              func(); // вызываем функцию аякса из хеша  
            }
          }, 150);
        },
        AjaxFromHash = function () {
          var id, value, arg, i = 0,
            pairs = hash.slice(1).split('&'),
            // разбиваем хеш на пары  
            length = pairs.length;
          for (; i < length; i++) { // перебираем все пары  
            arg = pairs[i].split('='); // разбваем пару на id и значение  
            $('#' + arg[0]).val(arg[1]); // меняем значения полей  
          }
          $('#search_form').trigger('submit'); // запускаем отправку формы  
        },
        getData = function ($this) { // получаем данные из формы и записываем их в виде строки запроса  
          var data = '';
          $this.find('input[type="text"], select').each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            if (data) data += '&';
            data += $this.attr('name') + '=' + $this.val();
          });
          return data;
        },
        sendQuery = function (event) { // отправка данных аяксом  
          event.preventDefault(); // отменяем поведение по умолчанию  
          $this = $(this);
          data = getData($this);
          $.ajax({
            url: $this.attr('action'),
            // получем из формы адрес отправки  
            data: data,
            type: $this.attr('method'),
            // получем из формы метод  
            success: Success // обработчик успеха  
          });
        },
        Success = function (html) { // обработчик успеха  
          $('#print').html(html); // выводим принятые данные (в нашем случае это html? если данные будут гоняться в json-e, нужно писать отдельный парсер)  
          hash = '#' + data; // изменяем текущее значени переменной для слежки  
          window.location.hash = data; // изменяем хеш  
        },
        Init = function () { // инициация функции  
          $(function () {
            $('#search_form').bind('submit', sendQuery); // навешиваем событие для формы  
            //          hash = window.location.hash; // запоминаем текущий хеш (если не выставить то сразу произойдёт запрос с данными в хеше)  
            DetectHash(AjaxFromHash); // отслеживаем изменение в хеше  
          });
        };
      return Init; // в случае обращения к AjaxSearch запускаем функцию Init  
    }();
  AjaxSearch();
})();
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
<div>  
<form action="1.html" method="post" id="search_form">  
  <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />  
  <select name="country" id="country">  
    <option value="0">Страна</option>  
    <option value="1">Беларусь</option>  
    <option value="2">Польша</option>  
  </select>  
  <select name="style" id="style">  
    <option value="0">Стиль</option>  
    <option value="1">Альтернатива</option>  
    <option value="2">Инди</option>  
  </select>  
  <input type="submit" value="Найти" />  
</form>  
</div>  
<div id="print">  
</div>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: @RedMonkey, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.